# How to make a button appear again after making it disappear?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I'm trying to make a button that will disappear when i click it and then re-appear when I click it again.

This where I am so far:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
    [sg.Text("Converter", enable_events = True, key = 'text'), sg.Spin(['item 1', 'item 2'])],
    [sg.Button("Button", key = 'Button1')],
    [sg.Input(key = 'input', enable_events = True)],
    [sg.Text("New line"), sg.Button("New button", key = 'Button2')]
]




window = sg.Window('Converter', layout)
go = True
while go:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

    if event == 'Button1':
        window['text'].update(visible = False)





window.close()
```

So far it only makes the button disappear. I don't know how to make the click (event) make it go back to the starting state.

Comment: You may need to use the `pin` layout helper function to keep the `Button` from moving when it re-appears.  There are Demo Programs to help show how `pin` works.

Answer (score 0):

Because `visible` is often a boolean property of an object (it's either `True` or `False`), you can use its current value to cause a toggling behavior like you are after by setting visibility to `not object.visible`. So if it's currenty `False` then `not False` will resolve to `True` and vice versa.

```
if event == 'Button1':
    window['text'].update(visible = not window['text'].visible)
```

Comment: yes it works this way, thank you for helping me this is my 3rd week of learning python got a long way ahead of me 
would you mind explaning to me how this code you wrote works? i mean i do understand what you did here but the last part (visible = not window['text'].visible) i'm looking at it trying to understand how it works and it's very confusing.

Comment: `window['text']` has a property called `visible` that will return a boolean (a `True` or a `False` value) depending on if the `window['text']` is currently visible or not. So if it's currently visible `window['text'].visible` will return `True`. Because it's currently visible, we want to set it to `False`, so we toss `not` in front of it since `not True` = `False`. So all this really says is `window['text'].update(visible = False)` when the current visibility is `True`. If we run it again, it will effectievly say `window['text'].update(visible = True)` since the current state is `False`.

Comment: That's a little strange to see at first, but once you get your head wrapped around it, you'll find usage for this type of a pattern every time you want to toggle something. Kind of psuedo code way of thinking about it: `object.toggleable_property.set(not object.toggleable_property.current_value)`

Answer (score -1):

you need a bool variable for toggling

```
textVisible = True
#....

    if event == 'Button1':
        textVisible = not textVisible
        window['text'].update(visible = textVisible)
```

Comment: Thank you for helping i still don't understand.

Comment: *"you need a bool variable for toggling"* - No, [you do not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77807754/1889329). Introducing redundant state is actively harmful.